# Im struggling to work the camera in a small space

Tags: camera

This is a tutorial im following i want to make it so my camera shows the same amount of area as his does but i dont know how, i'm quite new to blender and any help would be much appreciated

[image]
[image]

Basically im trying to increase how much u can see, i want to be abe to see more of the room but if i go any further back i wll go through the wall.

This is a tutorial im following i want to make it so my camera shows the same amount of area as his does but i dont know how, i'm quite new to blender and any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your camera's *Focal Length*.
The tutorial uses 18mm.

Go to *Camera > Lens > Focal Length* (it's 50mm by default)

[image]